# Can you assign data inside a GET method to an outside variable in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, http, get

In the below code, I am trying to assign the contents of testdata to the values in checkList. The problem I am getting is that checkList is undefined when the loop begins. I can't seem to figure out how to solve this issue, it seems like no matter what I do either checkList or testdata is undefined.

I am a newbie with Angular and I am wondering if this has something to do with the async properties of the get method?

```
  masterSelect: Boolean;
  checkList: any;
  fileNames$: any;
  testdata: string[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.checkList = [
      {id:1,value:'Section1',isSelected:false},
      {id:2,value:'Section2',isSelected:false},
      {id:3,value:'Section3',isSelected:false},
      {id:4,value:'Section4',isSelected:false},
      {id:5,value:'Section5',isSelected:false},
      {id:6,value:'Section6',isSelected:false},
      {id:7,value:'Section7',isSelected:false},
    ]

    this.fileNames$ = this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + "Invoice/GetFileNames").subscribe(function (data) {

      this.testdata = data;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.testdata.length; i++) {
        //console.log(this.testdata[i])
        this.checkList[i].value = this.testdata[i];

      }

    }, function (error) {
      this.testdata = error;
    });

    this.masterSelect = false;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign an empty value to the arrays before using them as given below -

```
  this.checkList = [];
  this.checkList = [
  {id:1,value:'Section1',isSelected:false},
  {id:2,value:'Section2',isSelected:false},
  {id:3,value:'Section3',isSelected:false},
  {id:4,value:'Section4',isSelected:false},
  {id:5,value:'Section5',isSelected:false},
  {id:6,value:'Section6',isSelected:false},
  {id:7,value:'Section7',isSelected:false},
]
```

Same for test data as well -

```
this.fileNames$ = this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + "Invoice/GetFileNames").subscribe(function (data) {
  this.testdata = []
  this.testdata = data;
```

Moreover, this type of code should be moved to `ngOnInit` rather than the constructor. The variable might not be available at the time when you are trying to access it.

Comment: Didn't seem to help. Still getting undefined for checkList.

Comment: You can try to move it into subscribe block as well as pointed out in the other answer. It might be happening that when your subscribe block gets triggered, your code execution has moved to some other location and these variables are not in memory. But in any case, this type of implementation should be done in ngOnInit and not constructor unless until extremely necessary.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and although it does assign correctly, the variable is undefined when the page renders. I put in some breakpoints and I believe this is happening because its an async request so the assignment happens AFTER the page loads.

Comment: Yes, look into the lifecycle hooks - https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. As I have mentioned earlier move this code to your ngOnInit block rather than the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can move checklist into the subscribe.
My solution is:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

this.fileNames$ = this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + "Invoice/GetFileNames").subscribe(function (data) { 
this.checkList = [
  {id:1,value:'Section1',isSelected:false},
  {id:2,value:'Section2',isSelected:false},
  {id:3,value:'Section3',isSelected:false},
  {id:4,value:'Section4',isSelected:false},
  {id:5,value:'Section5',isSelected:false},
  {id:6,value:'Section6',isSelected:false},
  {id:7,value:'Section7',isSelected:false},
]

  this.testdata = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.testdata.length; i++) {
    //console.log(this.testdata[i])
    this.checkList[i].value = this.testdata[i];

  }

}, function (error) {
  this.testdata = error;
});

this.masterSelect = false;
```

}

Comment: Interesting. So that works to reassign values, however once the page loads, the checkList variable is undefined again.